# Route won't return view Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, frameworks

I'm trying to build an API with Laravel. I already did some projects with this framework but never had this kind of issue I'm dealing with now.
In the picture you see my routes which I have build.

The first one just opens the Laravel welcome page, the second returns all my users in json.

But in the last route I simply want to return a view I just created, but when visiting the URL I just get a blank white page with no content, error message or log.

I simply added a new newuser.blade.php view in my views folder.

[image: http://i61.tinypic.com/311nt5g.png]

Comment: How about you actually put the code in the question instead of a picture?

Comment: do you have some content in that blade file ?can you share some code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code would help, although from the picture you simply need to move your `users/new` route to above the `users/{id}` one.

Laravel is passing 'new' as the $id parameter to UserController@UserById. Changing the order means it will recognise the other route first.

```
    // above
    Route::get('users/new', function() {
        // return view
    });

    // below
    Route::get('users/{id}', 'UserController@UserById');
```

Comment: I'm sorry in the future I will post a code snippet. Youre solution worked, and it's clear why. Thanks!